# How to show values from resources for a boolean BoundField

Tags: asp.net, gridview, resources, localization

In a GridView, how to show in a boolean `BoundField` value from resources for each value (true, false).

For example: If the value is `true` then show "Value a" (from resources) else then show "Value B".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to make it Template field and then do like...

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" <%# Eval("ColumnName") == true ? 
Resources.GlobalRes.KeyNameA : 
Resources.GlobalRes.KeyNameB  %> ></asp:Label>
```

Comment: What is `Eval("Value B")` ? `Value A` is stored in a resource file

Comment: You mean values are stored in Local Resource file ?

Comment: @ Muhammad: Not exactly, they are stored in a global resource file